# How to improve the performance in snowpark procedure?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have below procedure for merging and truncating table based on certain keys. The procedure looks fine, but it seems some performance issue

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE table_merge(keys Array)
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE PYTHON
  RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.8'
  PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
  HANDLER = 'reverse_str'
AS
$$
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import when_matached
def table_merge(session,keys):
  df_src= session.table(source_table)
  df_tgt= session.table(target_table)
  key_conditon = None
  for key in deletion_keys:
    if condition = None:
       condition = df_src[key]==df_tgt[key]
    else:
        condition = condition & (df_src[key]==df_tgt[key])
  df_tgt.merge(df_src, condition, [when_matched().delete()])

  return 'Pass'
$$;
```

when i ran the above query, it taking around 28.seconds even for 3 records?

So to check the execution using normal snowflake query, i tried with below query

```
merge into  target_table t using (select "ID", "NAME" from source_table) s on s.ID = t.ID and s.NAME = t.NAME when matched then delete
```

But above query executed, but it didn't merge as expected

#Expected:

1. Merge data from source to Target
2. While merging , if keys from source matches with target table, then truncate those rows in the target table, then insert new data from source in to the target
3. Keys for truncate should be dynamic, so the query statement should able to truncate rows based on keys which is being passed in to the procedure.

Any solution or recommendation to improve the query?

Comment: Do you really need a py proc  ? isnt this simple as `delete from target where key in (select key from src)` or may be `key in (1,2,3...)` ? Why not firing this proc directly?

Comment: Hi @KoushikRoy yes its a requirement suggested by the business.. however would be appreciate if could suggest the best solution ?

Comment: My suggestion would be, 1. see what is this proc supposed to do? 2. Implement it in simple SQL. If you cant, you can post the logic here and we can help. But looking at your procedure, i dont think its complex and its similar to `delete from target where key in (select key from src)`. And the major problem with your proc is, if you have to delete 1000 rows, your proc will take ages to finish.

Comment: Hi @KoushikRoy, i have updated question with expected use cases. IF  simple sql procedure is sufficient, then please help with the logic. We choose snowpark as it enables the capability for dynamically truncating rows against array of keys that is being passed in to the procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two ways to solve this.

Option 1. Delete and insert - This is faster because of bulk operation. In your py procedure, your input is keys. So,
First delete based on keys -

```
delete from target_table where keys in (select keys from src_table) and keys in (input_keys)
```

Second, insert data from source -

```
insert into target_table  select * from src_table where keys in (input_keys)
```

Option 2 - Using Merge. This will be slower since merge is slower operation.

```
merge into  target_table t using (select "ID" sid, "NAME" sname from source_table keys in (input_keys)) s on s.ID = t.ID and s.NAME = t.NAME when matched then UPDATE 
set  id=sid, name=sname;
```

You really dont have to delete it. You just have to update all your columns from data coming from source.

Comment: ok. Thanks @Koushik.. so for the first option1- how can pass keys dynamically in to the statement-

Comment: same way you are currently passing `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE table_merge(keys Array)`